# Can you "cd" into an AWS S3 bucket and a run a powershell script there

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

Is it possible to `cd` into AWS S3 buckets in powershell, and run a script on that directory as if it were on your local machine?

I've set up the credentials, but can't seem to find any articles on navigating through buckets using powershell.

Comment: This sounds a bit of an [XY Scenario](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you can't do what you're after.  Firstly, you shouldn't think that there's really any single machine behind the S3 storage where you could run the script in the first place.  Secondly, the items don't exist in directories, even if they may be represented that way - the full "path" to each item is it's full key, they don't exist in a tiered structure.  What is it you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: You could of course run a powershell script locally that queries and interacts with S3 - is that what you're asking?

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to run a script that will go through every directory within the bucket (there are thousands each containing a single .csv file) and write that .csv file to a SQL table. I've written a powershell script that does this, but it needs to be run from the outer directory containing all the thousands of inner directories.

Comment: Given that what you're describing sounds like you're going to end up reading every file from S3 anyway, why not just download the entire bucket and run the whole thing locally?  You could script the downloading part if necessary, but if you've already got the code working from local directories, that's probably the most efficient way of making it work.

Comment: You could script to recursively pull each folder down locally and run your script on it

Comment: Oh, okay. That actually makes sense. Could you point me to an article on scripting the downloading (or the recursive suggestion)?

Comment: aws cli: `aws s3 sync s3://yourbucket C:\folder` [doc link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: If you want to use the S3 powershell objects, the last example on [this docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Copy-S3Object.html) is pretty much all you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just download the bucket contents and run the script locally.

[AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

```
aws s3 sync s3://yourbucket C:\folder
```

AWS Powershell:

```
Copy-S3Object -BucketName yourbucket -KeyPrefix * -LocalFolder C:\folder
```

Comment: The keys of the objects that I want to copy (.csv files) don't seem to have a common prefix, though. They are all within a common folder, however. But it seems like this has no bearing on the key. To copy a bunch of files this way, it seems like their keys need to share a common prefix.

Comment: `KeyPrefix` is nothing to do with the object name. Key is the 'folder' you see in the aws web console. You can update `KeyPrefix` to download a folder (and contents) eg: `myfolder` or `myfolder/subfolder`.